# Computing Pointwise Mutual Information in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to compute [pointwise mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information) (PMI).

[image]

I have two RDDs as defined here for p(x, y) and p(x) respectively:

```
pii: RDD[((String, String), Double)]
 pi: RDD[(String, Double)]
```

Any code I'm writing to compute PMI from the RDDs `pii` and `pi` is not pretty. My approach is first to flatten the RDD `pii` and join with `pi` twice while massaging the tuple elements.

```scala
val pmi = pii.map(x => (x._1._1, (x._1._2, x._1, x._2)))
             .join(pi).values
             .map(x => (x._1._1, (x._1._2, x._1._3, x._2)))
             .join(pi).values
             .map(x => (x._1._1, computePMI(x._1._2, x._1._3, x._2)))
// pmi: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), Double)]
...
def computePMI(pab: Double, pa: Double, pb: Double) = {
  // handle boundary conditions, etc
  log(pab) - log(pa) - log(pb)
}
```

Clearly, this sucks. Is there a better (idiomatic) way to do this?
Note: I could optimize the logs by storing the log-probs in `pi` and `pii` but choosing to write this way to keep the question clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `broadcast` would be a solution.

```scala
val bcPi = pi.context.broadcast(pi.collectAsMap())
val pmi = pii.map {
  case ((x, y), pxy) =>
    (x, y) -> computePMI(pxy, bcPi.value.get(x).get, bcPi.value.get(y).get)
}
```

Assume: `pi` has all `x` and `y` in `pii`.