# How to write these code in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Pyspark to compute PMI(Point Mutual Infomation).
And I found Scala code at

[Computing Pointwise Mutual Information in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620297/computing-pointwise-mutual-information-in-spark)

I already wrote a Python version from the original code written by Delip.

How to translate the Scala code written by emeth into Python version?

Here is my code:

```
counts = RDD["String", int]
twocounts = RDD["String1String2", int]

MI = twocounts.map(lambda x: (x[0][0], (x[0], x[1]))) \
          .join(counts) \
          .map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0][1], x[1]) ) \
          .join(counts) \
          .map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0][0], x[1][0][0][1], x[1][0][1], x[1][1])) \
          .map(lambda x: (x[0], computeMI(x[1], x[2], x[3])))


def computeMI(pab, pa, pb):
    return math.log(pab) - math.log(pa) - math.log(pb)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? The code you have written does not work or something?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. My code works fine but is ugly. I would like to know how to translate the Scala code from emeth into equivalent python code. Following is his code
    val bcPi = pi.context.broadcast(pi.collectAsMap())
    val pmi = pii.map {
      case ((x, y), pxy) =>
        (x, y) -> computePMI(pxy, bcPi.value.get(x).get, bcPi.value.get(y).get)
    }